# Swift 4 - Cannot invoke 'Spaceship.init' with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my code. I've been stuck on this for a while. I just can't seem to figure it out. The guide that I'm following wants me to super.init() in the Fighter subclass, but it seems to give me an error every time I try.

```
class Spaceship {
    var name = String()
    var health = Int()
    var position = Int()
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    init(health: Int) {
        self.health = health
    }
    init(position: Int) {
        self.position = position
    }
    func moveLeft() {
        position -= 1
    }
    func moveRight() {
        position += 1
    }
    func wasHit() {
        health -= 5
    }
}
```

---

```
class Fighter: Spaceship {
    let weapon: String
    var remainingFirePower: Int
    init(remainingFirePower: Int) {
        self.remainingFirePower = remainingFirePower
    }
    init(weapon: String) {
        self.weapon = weapon
        super.init() //Cannot invoke 'Spaceship.init' with no arguments
    }
    func fire() {
        if remainingFirePower > 0 {
            remainingFirePower -= 1
        } else {
            print("You have no more fire power.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All of your initializers for `SpaceShip` take an argument.  You have to call one of your initializers and pass the argument it requires, or add an initializer to `SpaceShip` that takes no arguments.

Comment: So, I tried to do super.init(name: "") and similar for the other 2. It still didn't work. Apparently, I'm not allowed to have more than one super.init declarations. I also tried to comma out the first idea and that didn't work either. Could you maybe give me an example?

Comment: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/596ec586c721ee1b86ab9542

Comment: `remainingFirePower` dont have the initial value in `init(weapon...` , you also need to add that

Comment: Thank you so very much, vacawama! (I just figured that out also, Tj3n, thank you)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have an initializer that sets all your instance variables in your class to a passed value. Unless there are specific valid default values, it’s quite odd to have a separate `init` for each value.  I recommend you read about [designated initializers](http://www.codingexplorer.com/designated-initializers-convenience-initializers-swift/) and probably modify your code to have an `init(name:health:position:)` initializer in `Spaceship` and an `init(name:health:position:weapon:remainingFirePower:)` initializer in `Fighter` calling super’s implementation and passing values.

If there any values that you would never want to be blank strings or zeros, you should not provide defaults for them and therefore require them in the initializer.

This is the equivalent of your code modified to have a designated initializer that sets everything and has default values.

```
class Spaceship {
    var name : String
    var health : Int
    var position : Int
    init(name: String = "", health: Int = 0, position: Int = 0) {
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.position = position
    }
    func moveLeft() {
        position -= 1
    }
    func moveRight() {
        position += 1
    }
    func wasHit() {
        health -= 5
    }
}

class Fighter: Spaceship {
    let weapon: String
    var remainingFirePower: Int
    init(name: String = "", health: Int = 0, position: Int = 0, weapon: String = "", remainingFirePower: Int = 0) {
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.remainingFirePower = remainingFirePower
        super.init(name: name, health: health, position: position)
    }

    func fire() {
        if remainingFirePower > 0 {
            remainingFirePower -= 1
        } else {
            print("You have no more fire power.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy crap! That makes so much sense! Thank you!